# amp; prefix to $_POST/$_GET keys

Tags: php, xampp, http-request

One of my end users is quering my web service (written in php) but the request is all mest up.

All the $_POST/$_GET array keys except the first one got **amp;** prefix.

I understand that something is escaping the http quesy string and transforming the **&** to **`&amp;`**.

so a request like this:

```
service=inPhone&price=20&lang=0
```

turns to:

```
service=inPhone&amp;price=20&amp;lang=0
```

which makes the $_POST/$_GET look like this: (print_r result)

```
Array ( [service] => inPhone [amp;price] => 20 [amp;lang] => 0 )
```

.

The end uset is using xampp 1.7 with php 5.2 and the problem is manifesting when using curl and fopen.

any ideas for what i or the end user can do ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on the Query String

```
// This one
service=inPhone&amp;price=20&amp;lang=0
```

Comment: the end user code is using http_build_query and the script is runing just find on other servers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your setup, but the & can be turned back into & by using [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` is the encoded version of `&`. You need to decode it with PHP ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)) when you receive it. I am recommending `urldecode` specifically.